# How many times do I have to blow up such a curve until it is smooth?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, curves

If I have parametrized a curve in the complex plane by $$x(t)=a_lt^l+\cdots+a_nt^n$$
$$y(t)=b_kt^k+\cdots+b_mt^m$$
and the image is reduced (there exist at least two exponents which are relatively prime), how many blow ups do I need to perform at the singularity at $t=0$ (the point (0,0)) until my curve is smooth?

Any good references for figuring this out?